# How can I listen for delegate response from another function?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I want to have a function called requestData, which will get the user's current location, and then performing a URL-request. I need the requestData-function to have a callback for when the request is completed, wether or not it succeeded. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
requestData(_ completion:@escaping ()->()){
    self.locationManager.requestLocation()
    // Wait for the location to be updated
    let location:CLLocation? = //myLocation
    self.performRequest(with: location, completion: completion)
}
func performRequest(with location:CLLocation?, completion:@escaping ()->()){
    //Does the URL-request, and simply calls completion() when finished.
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {//Success}
    else{//Error}
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) 
{//Error}
```

My thoughts are to call requestData, it will request myLocation, and then call performRequest. But CLLocationManager does `requestLocation` with delegate-callbacks rather than a block. How should I do this?
Everything would've been great if requestLocation would've been like this:

```
self.locationManager.requestLocation( { (locations, error) in
    if locations {}
    else {}
})
```

But it's not..

To clarify, this is code in a widget (TodayExtension), which, as I understand, needs the callback, as I need the `widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler:)` to wait for my own completionHandler before triggering its own.

Comment: You can use CLLocation and check the time and accuracy of the location you get before you make the call to performRequest(). That way you know that the location is as accurate and updated as possible.

Comment: You can save the callback handler in a property and then invoke it from the delegate method

Answer (score 0):

The CLLocation contains several data to check the accuracy and time for the location you get. A solution for you could be to check the accuracy of this data before you make the request to performRequest().

Check out the documentation for the [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocation) and look at my pseudo code below. In de `didUpdateLocations` you can get an idea of what I think might be a solution for you. I wrote it directly in SO so don't hate on the errors.

But basically use:

> var horizontalAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy { get }
>
> var verticalAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy { get }
>
> var timestamp: Date { get }

```
 let location:CLLocation? //myLocation

func requestData(){
    self.locationManager.requestLocation()
    // Wait for the location to be updated

}
func performRequest(with location:CLLocation?, completion:@escaping ()- >()){
//Does the URL-request, and simply calls completion() when finished.
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
if let location = locations.first {
    //When the location is accurate enough we can call
    //the performRequest()
  
   if location.horizontalAccuracy < 15 && location.timestamp > (Date().timestampSince1970 - 60){
        //Accurate enough?? Then do the request
         self.performRequest(with: location, completion: completion)
    
   }else{
       //Not accurate enough...wait to the next location update
   }

}
else{//Error}
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) 
{//Error}
```